# Why is error coming while using mongoose connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
node:internal/errors:465 
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
 ^  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL     
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)     
at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:563:9)     
at new URL (node:internal/url:643:5)     
at new HostAddress (C:\Users\Bulgan Munkhbayar\OneDrive\Desktop\news\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:1023:36)     
at fromString (C:\Users\Bulgan Munkhbayar\OneDrive\Desktop\news\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:1073:16)     
at Array.map (<anonymous>)     
at parseOptions (C:\Users\Bulgan Munkhbayar\OneDrive\Desktop\news\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:220:45)     
at new MongoClient (C:\Users\Bulgan Munkhbayar\OneDrive\Desktop\news\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:63)     
at C:\Users\Bulgan Munkhbayar\OneDrive\Desktop\news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:16     
at new Promise (<anonymous>) {   input: 'mongodb://localhost:270717',   code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL' }  Node.js v17.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
mongodb://localhost:270717
```

into

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```